# Modify POST request into GET Request within Cypress XHR

Tags: cypress

my web application raises POST XHR request and I want to stop POST request and convert into GET request and then forward it to server, followed by check for 405 status code.
I can check response status code, but not able to modify request from POST to GET. Any one have done this ?

Tried with multiple options,

Code Snip 1: like other headers I tried to used 'Request Method', but didn't work

```
then('saving the new user form', () => {
    cy.typeText('#nameInput > input', 'Test ');
    cy.typeText('#mobileInput > input', '1234567890');
    cy.typeText('#emailInput > input', 'test@gmail.com');
    cy.server()

    cy.route('POST','/api').as('saveUserBtn')

    cy.get('#bottomSaveUserButton').click()

    cy.wait('@saveUserBtn')

    cy.get('@saveUserBtn').should((xhr) => {
        expect(xhr.requestBody).to.have.property('Request Method', 'GET')
    })
  });
```

& here is the error :
AssertionError
expected [ Array(1) ] to have property 'Request Method'
cypress/support/step_definitions/asvs/verb2.js:19:41
17 |
18 |     cy.get('@saveUserBtn').should((xhr) => {

> 19 |         expect(xhr.requestBody).to.have.property('Request Method', 'GET')
> |                                         ^
> 20 |     })
> 21 |   });
> 22 |

Code Snip 2: This snip always raises another POST request & not GET

```
then('saving the new user', () => {
    cy.typeText('#nameInput > input', 'Test ');
    cy.typeText('#mobileInput > input', '1234567890');
    cy.typeText('#emailInput > input', 'test@gmail.com');
    cy.clickElement('bottomSaveUserButton');

    cy.server().should((server) => {
        expect(server.method).to.eq('GET')
    })

    cy.server({
        method: 'POST'
    })
    cy.route({
        method:'POST',
        url:'api'
    }).as('saveUserBtn')

    cy.clickElement('bottomSaveUserButton');

    cy.wait('@saveUserBtn').should('have.property', 'status', 200)
    });
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet that you have tried along with the error screenshots or error messages that you got ?

Comment: above code is snip 2

Comment: I'm getting all mock & subbing options for all other headers except Method:GET instead of Method:POST

Comment: Hey it would be great if you can update all these details in your main question.

Comment: added code into the main section